# IIS Returns 500 when posting large JSON Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am posting a JSON object that contains an array with about 2000 objects.  When I post it to the server like this:

```
            self.SelectedEvent().SaveEvent = function () {
                var json = ko.toJSON(self.SelectedEvent().MembersAttended);
                self.SelectedEvent().NotFoundMembers(null);
                alert(json);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Event/SaveEvent/',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(self.SelectedEvent)
                })
            }
```

I get a 500 error.  When I reduce the amount of objects in the array to 150 the post works fine.  Is there a limit on the size of the post data?  Would I be better breaking this data up?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Update:

Server side code:

```
    public void SaveEvent(Event eventToSave)
    {
        var x = eventToSave;
    }
```

At this point this action is not being hit.  It is failing before it gets here.

Comment: Add server side code that receive data.

Comment: Maybe break in the server code and see what exception is prompting the 500 status?

Comment: Servers usually have maximum request size in order to avoid denial of service attack.

Answer (score 3):

There could be other reasons why you are getting HTTP 500, as it is a generic server error. But without knowing whats going on server side max request length is probably your culprit if your request is larger than 4mb.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="4096" />
</system.web>
```

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.